# Facebook canvas app redirecting to Facebook logo

Tags: ruby-on-rails, facebook, omniauth

I am using OmniAuth gem to develop a Facebook canvas application and when I click log in, it just redirects me to a blank page that has the Facebook logo and then you have to click that again. Is there a way to make it so that it goes directly to the permission page?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the problem you're experiencing is that when a redirect is performed using Javascript you actually redirect the iframe and not the whole web page. This causes a facebook page to be displayed inside an iframe, which gets detected and causes the logo + blank page to appear instead. What you want is to perform a redirect on the whole page. This can be achieved using:

```
window.top.location = somelocation;
```

Comment: Thanks this worked I put this in a function once the log in link is click `function redirect(url) {
   return window.top.location.replace(url);
 }`

Comment: This window.top.location works but then when the app redirects back to the root, it goes to the url root and doesn't load the root inside the facebook iframe.

Comment: Yea, I had a similar issue. You have to set the redirect back address to `apps.facebook.com/yourapp/path/inside/your/app`.